# Convert audio CMSampleBuffer to MTLBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, metal, cmsamplebuffer, mtlbuffer

What is the most efficient way to convert audio `CMSampleBuffer` buffers to `MTLBuffer` buffers? I would also like to efficiently as possible convert `MTLBuffer` buffers back to `CMSampleBuffer` buffers.

Do I need to first convert audio `CMSampleBuffer` to NSData, then use `makeBuffer(bytesNoCopy pointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, length: Int, ...)`? Or is there a more direct approach?

Comment: Are you operating on audio or video sample buffers? Either way, you shouldn't need to go through `NSData`; you can ask a sample buffer for its corresponding block buffer or image buffer, from which you can get a raw pointer to the data. You'll probably want to take a copy in each direction if you're going to be processing with Metal; otherwise you'll be holding onto resources that might be in a tightly-constrained pool (e.g. a `CVPixelBufferPool`) for longer than they should strictly be kept alive.

Comment: Thanks to your amazing help I already have pixel buffers working. Now I am trying to add some audio processing. Thanks for the advice.